# Stroke on small SVG circles issue in iOS10's Safari

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm using a SVG overlay in leaflet with D3.js and when I zoom it's scaled and then I resize my elements to make them fit.

The problem i'm having is that in Safari at iOS10 the stroke of the circles get drawn as a rect when the radius of the circle is smaller than 1. Here is a a js-fiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/k8kLfvxv/2/

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <g>
    <circle r="0.5" cx="3" cy="3" fill="red" transform="scale(10)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" ></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Every other browser I have tried works just perfect.

Anyone know anything about this issue?

Comment: any chance you can post a screenshot of what you're seeing on ios10 safari? is there a reason you're using `scale` to change the size of your circle rather than adjusting its other attributes or using css like here https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/?

Comment: report it as a webkit bug if it's not already reported.

Comment: That would be an option, to bad we are going into production very soon :(

Comment: what happens if you use transform in the other direction? ie. make the dots 50px to start and `scale(0.1)` (thinking that the decimal stroke is the issue)?

Comment: I think I will just ditch the scale-approach. I use a small lib [link](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay) to handle the rendering of the SVG so the scale thing is kind of enforced in this way. Will try to fork it and do my changes then report the issue as a bug to apple...if I get it right i can post the github here.